# Definite integral of function not coming out as a constant

Tags: numerical-integration

I'm trying to integrate a double integral of 2(x+y) on the bounds of y/2 to y dx, and 0 to 1 dy. When I do this, I end up not getting a constant, which I do when I manually integrate it and check with other calculates. I'm very new to Mathematica and just trying to get the hang of it.

Here's what I've done.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You need to check the [`Integrate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Integrate.html) documentation on the integration order, what you wrote is the integration by `y` first, and `x` after that.

The correct form is:

```
Integrate[fxy, {y,0,1}, {x,y/2,y}]
(* 7/12 *)
```